# Error updating listview periodically handler and AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-asynctask

staff

have a rather odd problem. I have a chat that consists of a listview where messages are displayed.

Tenhoum handler that calls a assynktask every 5 seconds to update the conversation, so getting new messages. The message comes in xml below. In the emulator works perfectly with android 2.2 to 4.4, have problems, just the listview does not update.

Ie, I have a problem that only manifests itself in production. Everything usually works on emulators, but when I install the app in android 2.2 to 4.4, the listview is not updated and displays nothing.

I'm sorry for maybe posting a doubt these, but do not know what might be going into production error. It would be some thread, asynktasks or handler? I've done podificações using threads, timers, runOnUiThreads it all works, but on emulators.

The production environment has everything the app needs, connection, internet and sdcard.

XML chat example message:

```
<ListaMensagensChat>
  <mensagem>
  <codigo>1449</codigo>
  <cd_emissor>1</cd_emissor>
  <para>rastronet</para>
  <mesagem>123</mesagem>
  <data_criacao>2014-08-04 10:22:18</data_criacao>
  <lida>NAO</lida>
</mensagem>
```

Activity chat:

```
package com.infovale.localizauto;

public class ConversaChatActivity extends Activity {

EditText txtMensagem;
TextView nomeUsuario;
String paraUsuario, codigoUsuario;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

ListView listView = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversa_chat);

    // txtHistorico = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtHistorico);
    txtMensagem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMensagem);
    nomeUsuario = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nomeUsuario);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

    paraUsuario = b.getString("codigo");

    nomeUsuario.setText(b.getString("nome"));

    Context c = getApplicationContext();

    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);

    codigoUsuario = sp.getString("CODIGO", null);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listConversa);

    mHandler.postDelayed(updateTask, 5000);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

    }
}

private Runnable updateTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        new getConversas().execute();

        mHandler.postDelayed(updateTask, 5000);
    }
};

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    try {

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    try {

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void Enviar(View v) {
    String r = "";

    final String mensagem = txtMensagem.getEditableText().toString();

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String url = WebService.URL_SERVER
                    + "WebService.php/?operacao=EnviaMensagemChat&EMISSOR="
                    + codigoUsuario + "&RECEPTOR=" + paraUsuario
                    + "&MENSAGEM=" + mensagem + "";

            String tagXML = "resultado";
            String tagresultado = "sucesso";

            String r = WebService.EnviaInformacao(getApplicationContext(),
                    url, tagXML, tagresultado);

            if (r.equals("SIM")) {

            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    txtMensagem.setText("");
                }
            });
        }
    });

    thread.start();

}

private class getConversas extends
        AsyncTask<String, String, List<mensagensChat>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected List<mensagensChat> doInBackground(String... args) {

        List<mensagensChat> list = new ArrayList<mensagensChat>();

        String urlWS_get = WebService.URL_SERVER
                + "WebService.php/?operacao=ListaMensagensChat&EMISSOR="
                + codigoUsuario + "&RECEPTOR=" + paraUsuario;

        int tamanho = -1;

        Hardware.ConnectingToInternet(getApplicationContext());
        try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(urlWS_get);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("mensagem");
            tamanho = nodes.getLength();

            mensagensChat u;

            Node node = nodes.item(0);

            int size = nodes.getLength();

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                node = nodes.item(i);

                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element element = (Element) node;

                    u = new mensagensChat();

                    u.codigo = getValue("codigo", element);
                    u.cd_emissor = getValue("cd_emissor", element);
                    u.para = getValue("para", element);
                    u.mesagem = getValue("mesagem", element);
                    u.data_criacao = getValue("data_criacao", element);
                    u.lida = getValue("lida", element);

                    list.add(u);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final List<mensagensChat> list) {
        // txtHistorico.setText("");

        if (list.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

        for (mensagensChat m : list) {

            if (m.cd_emissor == codigoUsuario) {
                items.add(new Item("Eu", m.mesagem));
            } else {
                items.add(new Item(m.para, m.mesagem));
            }
        }

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(ConversaChatActivity.this, items);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setSelection(listView.getCount() - 1);
    }
}

class mensagensChat {
    public String codigo;
    public String cd_emissor;
    public String para;
    public String mesagem;
    public String data_criacao;
    public String lida;
}

private static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
    NodeList nodes = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0)
            .getChildNodes();
    Node node = (Node) nodes.item(0);
    return node.getNodeValue();
}

class Item {

    private String title;
    private String description;

    public Item(String title, String description) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Item> itemsArrayList;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> itemsArrayList) {

        super(context, R.layout.layout_listview_chat, itemsArrayList);

        this.context = context;
        this.itemsArrayList = itemsArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // 1. Create inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // 2. Get rowView from inflater
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_listview_chat,
                parent, false);

        // 3. Get the two text view from the rowView
        TextView labelView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        TextView valueView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.value);

        // 4. Set the text for textView
        labelView.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
        valueView.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getDescription());

        // 5. retrn rowView
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

}